# Having trouble integrating payment gateway in my Django website

Tags: javascript, django, paytm

I have tried to see [this tutorial to make a Django E-Commerce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33pnWTslX2E.) website. In this the maker has added *PayPal* but I want to add *Paytm Gateway*.

My problem is that in the video there is a `submitformdata()` function which on payment approval saves the form data but I can't do it in *Paytm* integration as it does not give me and JavaScript code so that I can check the payment status in JavaScript and then call the `submitformdata()` accordingly.

Please suggest how to check if the payment is successful in JavaScript and the save the form data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include a [minimum, reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) In it's current form the question lacks details because the primary source should be included as text in the post, not as a reference to a youtube video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the paytm_dict as in their docs in context and use if else in javascript for checking transaction status and execute accordingly.This much i can tell without seeing your code

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. Also how to redirect to a certain page if the payment is successful

Comment: Thats a different question. Ask a new question and also provide code for better understanding to others